# java.lang.VerifyError : AbstractEpollUnsafe exception on Vertx, Dse application

Tags: maven, cassandra, vert.x, datastax-java-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am trying to run an application which uses Datastax library for DSE-graph

Project *pom.xml*

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>dse-driver</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vertx/vertx-hazelcast -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-platform</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>my.app.Server</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

When I am running this application on **windows** using `mvn exec:java` its **running fine**. But When I am running this application on **Ubantu** I am **getting this below error**.

```
    java.lang.VerifyError: class io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel$AbstractEpollUnsafe overrides final method beginRead.()V
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
            at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyUtil.<clinit>(NettyUtil.java:96)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.NettyOptions.eventLoopGroup(NettyOptions.java:99)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.<init>(Connection.java:769)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1400)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:159)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:330)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:305)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:247)
            at com.datastax.driver.core.DelegatingCluster.connect(DelegatingCluster.java:71)
            at com.datastax.driver.dse.DseCluster.connect(DseCluster.java:351)
            at my.app.datasource.db.DataSource.getSessionInstance(DataSource.java:73)
 at my.app.services.VertexService.getVertexByName(VertexService.java:59)
        at my.app.services.VertexService.getVertexIdByName(VertexService.java:77)
        at my.app.api.eventdetails.EventDetailsRequestHandler$2.handle(EventDetailsRequestHandler.java:52)
        at org.vertx.java.core.VoidHandler.handle(VoidHandler.java:27)
        at org.vertx.java.core.VoidHandler.handle(VoidHandler.java:24)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.DefaultHttpServerRequest.handleEnd(DefaultHttpServerRequest.java:314)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleEnd(ServerConnection.java:209)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.processMessage(ServerConnection.java:313)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.ServerConnection.handleMessage(ServerConnection.java:94)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.DefaultHttpServer$ServerHandler.doMessageReceived(DefaultHttpServer.java:710)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.DefaultHttpServer$ServerHandler.doMessageReceived(DefaultHttpServer.java:600)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.VertxHttpHandler.channelRead(VertxHttpHandler.java:72)
        at org.vertx.java.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:155)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
        at org.vertx.java.core.http.impl.cgbystrom.FlashPolicyHandler.channelRead(FlashPolicyHandler.java:53)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:321)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1280)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:890)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:564)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:505)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:419)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:391)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT 1 :** added `mvn dependency:tree`

```
 [dependency:tree {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] my.app:app1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.datastax.cassandra:java-dse-graph:jar:1.0.0-beta1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:dse-driver:jar:1.1.1-beta1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-groovy:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-core:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tinkerpop:gremlin-shaded:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.carrotsearch:hppc:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.jcabi:jcabi-manifests:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.jcabi:jcabi-log:jar:0.14:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.21:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:indy:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-groovysh:jar:indy:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- jline:jline:jar:2.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-console:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-swing:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |        \- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:jar:indy:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-jsr223:jar:indy:2.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.jeremyh:jBCrypt:jar:jbcrypt-0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tinkerpop:tinkergraph-gremlin:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- io.vertx:vertx-core:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- io.vertx:vertx-hazelcast:jar:2.1.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:3.2.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- net.sourceforge.findbugs:annotations:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- io.vertx:vertx-platform:jar:2.1.5:provided
[INFO] +- redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:jar:2.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] \- org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile
```

Comment: Delete jars from folder .mvn at your home in Ubuntu, and try to download all the dependency again.May be any wrong version dependency were on class-path that is not compatible.

Comment: tried din't helped.  I deployed this on two ubuntu server on cloud and got same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the below command from project home folder,

> mvn dependency:tree

And find the version of below dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
    <artifactId>netty-transport-native-epoll</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

May be multiple versions are available of this dependency.

You can exclude any specific version from any dependency if required as below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>parent-dependency-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>${parent.dependency.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>parent-dependency-group</groupId>
                <artifactId>parent-dependency</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

As per dependency tree, replace

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId> 
    <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId> 
    <version>2.1.5</version>
    <exclusions> 
        <exclusion> 
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId> 
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId> 
        </exclusion> 
    </exclusions> 
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>io.netty</groupId> 
    <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId> 
    <version>4.0.37.Final</version> 
</dependency>
```

In your POM

Comment: `mvn dependency:tree | grep netty
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.21.Final:compile
`

Comment: I got above output `mvn dependency:tree` by running this command

Comment: I am not sure, because I didn't checked the classes inside netty-all dependency, but you can try. Exclude the dependency netty-all and add the same explicitly in your pom file with version 4.0.37

Comment: how can I know which library is downloading `netty-all` so that I can exclude it

Comment: It can be identify by analyzing dependency tree. If you carefully check the tree, it shows the dependency hierarchy. You can exclude the netty-all from the top most parent dependency (present in pom) . Share the whole dependency tree, I'll try to help you

Comment: could you please have a look at `mvn dependency:tree` added above in question

Comment: io.vertx:vertx-core:jar:2.1.5:compile brings io.netty:netty-all:jar:`4.0.21`.Final:compile but om.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
brings io.netty:netty-handler:jar:`4.0.37`.Final:compile. These versions must match, Exclude one of them.

Comment: Thanks @AnilAgrawal but little confusion here, why to add `netty-all` again

Comment: Because netty-all is required by vertx-core but no other dependency fetching it from repo. If it present under any other dependency tree, it don't require to add it explicitly in POM. Is your application working now?

Comment: yes working fine on ubuntu desktop without adding `netty-all`, though have not tested it on production.